# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I spent the whole day trying to solve the problem explained below. I would really appreciate a loooot if someone could point me my error.

When I package my Spark Java project and run it with spark-submit, the error happens at this line of code:

```
    DataFrame parquetFile = sqlContext.read().parquet("s3n://" +
                                                      aws_bucket_data + "/" +
                                                      aws_path);
```

When I runned the same program in Intellij, it worked fine (there are no connection issues with S3, abd the problem refers to DataFrame). I used Intellij to package the project. I know that DataFrame was substituted by DataSet in Spark 2.0.0, but I am using Spark 1.6.2!!!

```
16/11/15 19:51:17 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/usr/local/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-warehouse'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet([Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
    at org.test.Manager.run(Manager.java:55)
    at org.test.Runner.main(Runner.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

This is my POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>runner</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.3</jackson.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sedis</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedis_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacks_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.53</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-a</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>org.test.Runner</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>runner</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UPDATE:

I tried to compile with `mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests clean package -Xlint:deprecation`, and this is the detailed stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'lint' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/meeee/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'lint' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/meeee/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spark SQL 1.6.2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) does not include the missing method (`parquet(String path)`)

**[parquet for 2.0.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#parquet(java.lang.String))**

```
public Dataset<Row> parquet(String path)
```

> **Since: 2.0.0**

Use version 2.0.0 or above

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#parquet(java.lang.String)) that `public Dataset<Row> parquet(scala.collection.Seq<String> paths)` is supported since 1.4,0. I don't understand why then I am able to execute it from Intellij and why don't I get compilation errors? Could you please elaborate your answer replying to these doubts? Thanks.

Comment: When I change `spark.version` to 2.0.0 in my POM file, then it asks me to change DataFrame to Dataset. I did it and packaged the code again. When I execute it, it gives me this error: `[ERROR] /usr/test/Manager.java:[66,58] incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.sql.Row[]` regarding this code line `Dataset<Row> eventsRaw = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM mydata"); Row[] rddRows = eventsRaw.collect();`. Really do not understand what happens there....

Comment: Please see my Update. Maybe it will help us to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: @duckertito, but you are calling parquet(String).  Check this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets and update the question if you still have issues